# Zoom image lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a lightbox jQuery plugin which scales clicked images just like Highslide does http://highslide.com/#examples but it has to be small (Highslide's core is 57kb) and responsive.
It can be very simple. I don't need galeries etc.

Do you know good alternatives?

Comment: P.S: you can code your own in a couple of jQuery lines and some basic CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/recijo/4/)***

All you need:
add `data-darkbox` to your images:

```
<img data-darkbox src="image.jpg">
```

**CSS:**

```
/* DARKBOX STYLES */
#darkbox{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) no-repeat none 50%/contain;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 3000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity:0; visibility:hidden;
}
#darkbox.on{ 
    opacity:1; visibility:visible;
    height:90% !important; width:90% !important;
    left:5% !important; top:5% !important;
}
#darkbox:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0; top:0;
    font-size:2em;
    content:"\2A2F";
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $darkbox = $("<div/>",{id:"darkbox"}).on("click", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("on");
}).appendTo("body");
$('img[data-darkbox]').css({cursor:"pointer"}).on("click",function(){
    var o=this.getBoundingClientRect();
    $darkbox.css({
        transition:"0s",
        backgroundImage:"url("+this.src+")",
        left:o.left, top:o.top,
        height:this.height, width:this.width
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $darkbox.css({transition:".8s"}).addClass("on"); 
    },5);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a scaling effect instead of fadeIn/fadeOut?